# What's the best way to get an ActorRef from a Cluster given a relative path?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I have an Akka application having several nodes in a cluster.  Each node runs an assortment of different Actors, i.e. not all nodes are the same--there is some duplication for redundancy.

I've tried code like this to get a ref to communicate with an Actor on another node:

```
val myservice = context.actorSelection("akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/user/myService")
```

This works, because there is an Actor named myService running on the node at that address.  That feels like simple Akka Remoting though, not clustering, because the address is point-to-point.

I want to ask the cluster "Hey!  Anybody out there have an ActorRef at path "/user/myService"?", and get back one or more refs (depending on how many redundant copies are out there).  Then I could use that selector to communicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [Cluster Sharding](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/cluster-sharding.html), which would remove the need to know exactly where in the cluster your actors are located:

> Cluster sharding is useful when you need to distribute actors across several nodes in the cluster and want to be able to interact with them using their logical identifier, but without having to care about their physical location in the cluster, which might also change over time.

With Cluster Sharding, you don't need to know an actor's path. Instead, you interact with `ShardRegion` actors, which delegate messages to the appropriate node. For example:

```
val stoutRegion: ActorRef = ClusterSharding(system).shardRegion("Stout")
stoutRegion ! GetPint("guinness")
```

Comment: Interesting... The docs for this seem to use Actor singletons as examples.  Is that what its created for or will it work with a pool too?  Also wondering if PubSub is an option here, i.e. subscribe to a named topic.

Comment: Cluster Sharding is distinct from [Cluster Singleton](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/cluster-singleton.html). Perhaps [Distributed Publish Subscribe](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/distributed-pub-sub.html) would be useful to you as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to switch to cluster sharding but use your current deployment structure, you can use the ClusterReceptionist as described in the [ClusterClient docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-client.html).

However, this way you would have to register the actors with the receptionist before they are discoverable to clients.